# How to store Chinese in MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I already set

```
character-set-server = utf8
```

In `my.cnf`.

I restarted the server and recreated the database, but when I tried to insert Chinese into database, I received this error:

```
ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect string value: '\xE5\x93\x88\xE5\x93\x88' for│md=resource&f=source.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
column 'address' at row 1
```

Can someone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Is your column type plain `CHAR` or `VARCHAR`, or is it a [National Character Set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-national.html)?

Answer (score 0):

check you character set first

```
  SELECT CCSA.character_set_name 
  FROM information_schema.`TABLES` T,
       information_schema.`COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY` CCSA
WHERE CCSA.collation_name = T.table_collation
  AND T.table_schema = "schemaname"
  AND T.table_name = "tablename";
```